# Fruit identification - What is this green long fruit?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees, fruit

I found this fruit in the South of France, but I have no Idea what it is. It's a green, hard fruit. I tried to cut it to see the inside (on the following pictures).
It fell from a big tree, but I don't remember much information about it.

[image: the fruit]

[image: inside]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a photo of the plant?

Comment: Reminds me of *Theobroma cacao*, which almost certainly wouldn't grow that large (or at all?) in France (I wouldn't think). I'm not sure if any other Malvaceae plants grow similar fruits. I'll admit that the seemingly-circular stipule scar on the stem is reminiscent of a magnolia, but I don't know of any with a fruit like that. Overall, I ca't say I know European flora all that well...Can you provide more information (location, tree photos) and perhaps more pictures (seeds, tree leaves, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be a *Ceiba speciosa* pod? We have a lot of Silk Floss trees near where I live and they grow these types of pods. When they are fully developed, they burst open and are filled with cotton-like floss and dark seeds. I have never seen an unripe one opened up, but it definitely looks like the ones on the trees. The trees themselves are easily identifiable as well. They are large with greenish trunks that have thorns growing along the surface. Also, if you had previously seen the tree with large pink-purple flowers, that would be a good indication.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiba_speciosa

Comment: Please provide some reasoning with support.

Comment: I agree that the OP's specimen looks like a member of the Malvacaea and could very well be *Ceiba speciosa*. The OP's lack of more useful pictures and your (now improved) post still do not have me convinced, however. I find it strange that the OP mentioned `but I don't remember much information about [the tree]`, when the trunk of *C. speciosa* would be *quite* memorable I believe.  I'd recommend finding an image of *C. speciosa* fruit to include in your answer and adding some indication about how such a tropical fruit could be found in France. Both would strengthen your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it totally looks like Ceiba Speciosa ! I really don't remember the trunk tought, I think it was partially hidden behind a wall. But I've seen another specie of Ceiba ("Ceiba Insignis") in the same town, so it makes sense.